# Создание SFX архива

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск-библиотек

Подскажите, пожалуйста, либу, с помощью которой можно создавать sfx архивы.

Comment: Добавьте метку [tag:поиск-библиотек] и посмотрите её описание

Comment: Вы точно прочитали описание? Или чётких критериев нет и сами ничего не нашли?